# How to use different typemap for the same ModelMapper

Tags: java, json, jackson, modelmapper

I'm using ModelMapper to transform entity to dto, but we have a requirement that, same endpoints will be used by the multiple consumer. So, we have to restrict the fields based on the consumer.

Eg :

```
Consumer 1 -> fullName, aadharNo, other details...
Consumer 2 -> fullName, passportNo, other details...
Consumer 3 -> fullName, drivingLicenceNo
Consumer 4-> All fields


public class Student {
    private String fullName;
    private String aadharNo;
    private String passportNo;
    private String drivingLicenceNo;
    private String age;
    private String schoolName;
    private String collegeName;
    private String grade;
    private String schoolMark;
}

public class StudentDto {
    private String fullName;
    private String aadharNo;
    private String passportNo;
    private String drivingLicenceNo;
    private String age;
    private String schoolName;
    private String collegeName;
    private String grade;
    private String schoolMark;
}
```

I tried to achieve the same having multiple typeMap for the same model mapper, but not able to overwrite typemap once it is defined in modelmapper.

Sample PropertyMap :

```
   PropertyMap<Student , StudentDto> skipModifiedFieldsMap = new PropertyMap<Student , StudentDto>() {
      protected void configure() {
         //skip().setAadharNo(null);
     }
   };
```

Could you please suggest some good ways to achieve it. any library is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use [conditional mapping](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/property-mapping/#conditional-mapping) ?

This will allow you to create different conditions for different consumers and map accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The desired behavior can be achieved via using `typeMapName`

Configure named mappings

```
modelMapper.createTypeMap(Student.class, StudentDto.class, "Consumer1")
  .addMappings(new PropertyMap<>() {
                @Override
                protected void configure() {
                    skip(destination.getDrivingLicenceNo());
                }
   });

modelMapper.createTypeMap(Student.class, StudentDto.class, "Consumer2")
  .addMappings(new PropertyMap<>() {
                @Override
                protected void configure() {
                    skip(destination.getPassportNo());
                }
   });
```

Use named mappings

```
modelMapper.map(student, StudentDto.class, "Consumer1");
modelMapper.map(student, StudentDto.class, "Consumer2");
```

Unfortunately, This feature is not mentioned in ModelMapper [user manual](https://modelmapper.org/user-manual/)